# boot-class-path not allowed with target 11 failing on Windows

Tags: java-11, bootclasspath

I am upgrading IKVM codebase from Java 8  to Java 11, getting "boot-class-path not allowed with target 11"

```
<target name="classes" depends="clean-classes stubjars allsources.gen.lst AssemblyInfo.java PropertyConstants.java">
    <exec program="javac" useruntimeengine="false">
        <arg value="-J-Xmx1536M" />
        <arg value="-g" />
        <arg value="-nowarn" />
        <arg value="-implicit:none" />
        <arg value="-parameters" />
        <arg line="-cp dummy" />
        <arg value="-bootclasspath" />
        <arg path="mscorlib.jar;System.jar;System.Core.jar;System.Data.jar;System.Drawing.jar;System.XML.jar;../runtime/IKVM.Runtime.jar" />
        <arg value="@allsources.gen.lst" />
    </exec>
```

Comment: What are all those jar files and why are they delivered on the boot class path instead of the ordinary class path?

Comment: tried with normal class path and ended in following --error: package exists in another module: java.base
            [classes exec] package java.util.concurrent.atomic;
            [classes exec] ^

Comment: There’s a fundamental problem with software that requires to provide its own version of built-in classes. Did you try to compile your software without these libraries?

Comment: After removing this line         <arg path="mscorlib.jar;System.jar;System.Core.jar;System.Data.jar;System.Drawing.jar;System.XML.jar;../runtime/IKVM.Runtime.jar" />
error still exists, its not the jar file which are causing problem

Comment: Of course, the bootclasspath issue starts with the `<arg value="-bootclasspath" />` line.

Comment: actually This piece of code is from IKVM, which was compatible with JDK 8 now I am trying to build same with java 11, when I tried to compile with class path instead of bootclasspath I get the following error "--error: package exists in another module: java.base [classes exec] package java.util.concurrent.atomic; "

Comment: So you actually never plan to run the software on JDK 11 but want to compile for IKVM which might not even be able to cope with JDK 11 class files?

Comment: If you aiming at compiling for the unchanged IKVM, just adding `<arg line="-source 1.8 -target 1.8"/>` should solve your problems.

Comment: I thought this once... if its the correct way if we are upgrading code from jdk 8 to jdk 11, this error looks to be split package issue.. https://github.com/javapathfinder/jpf-core/issues/27